# Azure storage tables Rest API is throwing 403 - Server failed to authenticate the request even though auth token is passed

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to query Azure storage table using Rest API. here is what I am doing:

Step 1: fetching auth token using
GET : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token
[image]

Step 2: Using the auth token in step 1 I am calling Query table API as described in this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables

[image]

It is throwing 403 -server failed to authenticate the request error.
Isn't it the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorization with Azure AD is not supported for Azure Table storage.

Reference - [**Authorize access to Azure blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

> Authorization with Azure AD is available for all general-purpose and Blob storage accounts in all public regions and national clouds. Only storage accounts created with the Azure Resource Manager deployment model support Azure AD authorization. **Authorization with Azure AD is not supported for Azure Table storage.**

To authorize requests to Azure Table storage, you need to use [`Shared Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) or [`Shared access signatures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature).